# How to link a button with a specific post or page?

Tags: html, css

As I said in the title I am trying to link my buttons made in my code to the posts and files that I am trying to insert into the page.

As to give an example:
I made a page with 3 buttons that should act as seperate pages but I do not know how to make them, how should I say, excluded from one another.
This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<title>Skandaloza</title>
<style type="text/css">

body{margin:0 auto; width:980px; position:relative;} 
div.navMENU{ width:100%; height:50px;}
div.navMENU ul{list-style-type:none; padding:0px; margin:0 auto;}
div.navMENU li{float:left; padding:60px; margin:7px;}
div.navMENU a{display:block; width:180px; border-radius:10px: -moz-border-radius:10px; -webkit- 
border:10px;}
a:link{font-weight:bold; background-color:#ff0000; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;
padding:5px;}
a:hover{background-color:#0000ff;}
a:active{background-color:#0000ff;}
</style>

<body>

<div class="navMENU">
<h1 style="text-align:center"><font size="10" face="Cooper"> SKANDALOZA </font></h1>
<ul>

<li><a href="pagename#test" style="color: white"> POCETNA </a> </li>
<li><a href="#" style="color: white"> POSTOVI </a> </li>
<li><a href="#" style="color: white"> KONTAKT </a> </li>


</ul>

<video src="Gotovo.mp4" poster="initial_static_picture.jpg" width="1000" controls>
</video>

<hl style="text-align:left-side"><font size="10" face="Arial">GOTOVO JE - Jelena ubijena u KUCI 
Zoranovog rodjaka!</font></hl>

<body/>

<html/>
```

So can anyone with more expirience than I have (I am in forth grade of high school right now and I am from Europe) suggest something that will make it work as I intend it to work.

For example I want to connect this video that I inserted to just show on the page as mentioned (POSTOVI) and not show on the other two pages for the other two buttons.

If you need more explanation or a better one I am happy to oblige and do it better because this is my first time here and I would like to get pointers as to what I should and should not do!

Thank you very much kind strangers!

Comment: Welcome! Are you writing a separate html file for each page, or are you wanting this to be a single dynamic page?

Comment: @GammaGames I want this to be a single dynamic page because It is for a school assignment!

Comment: Okay, then I would recommend looking into using [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) to tell which items to show or hide.

You could wrap each special page with a container and toggle classes to hide and show different elements, same with the menu. I might be able to get a small demo later tonight, if that would help.

Comment: @GammaGames Thank you for your explanation and yes it would help a lot!

Comment: was my answer able to help?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'll try to make this in a few steps:

1. Create the "base" page

   I would create a base page that has the nav menu, footer, and a container for the page content. I would also add some classes for the nav menu (`active`, probably) to allow easy toggling for the nav menu's current page.
2. Create the views

   Inside the page content, I would create containers, each with an ID. Style them so they look alright, and then make the default `container` class hidden. Add another special class, `active` to show the containers when we want.
3. Add a function to switch active containers on hash change

   In the function, remove all `active` classes from the menu items and containers. Then, based on the current hash, add the `active` class back to the wanted containers. Add this function to window `hashchange` events and call the event on page load to make sure the home page starts up default.

And voilà, you've got a basic prototype up! Here's a snippet with the above.

And please note that there are frameworks out there that do all of this better (I enjoy using ([backbone](https://backbonejs.org/)), but my goal was to create a very basic page that shows different content based on the current url.

```js
function changeHash() {
  // Hide all containers and pause videos
  $("#nav a.item").removeClass("active");
  $(".container").removeClass("active");
  $("video")[0].pause();
  // Based on the hash, add a 
  //  "visible" class to the correct container
  switch (location.hash) {
    case "#video":
      $(`#nav a.item[href="#video"]`).addClass("active");
      $("#video").addClass("active");
      break;
    case "#about":
      $(`#nav a.item[href="#about"]`).addClass("active");
      $("#about").addClass("active");
      break;
    default:
      $(`#nav a.item[href="#"]`).addClass("active");
      $("#home").addClass("active");
  }
}

// Listen for hash changes and call on initial load
window.addEventListener('hashchange', changeHash);
changeHash();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #007fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav .item {
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#nav .item:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #007fff;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

#nav .item.active {
  background-color: #0059b3;
}

.container {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.container.active {
  display: unset;
}

#home img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

#video video {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#about p {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="nav">
  <a class="item" href="#">Home</a>
  <a class="item" href="#video">Video</a>
  <a class="item" href="#about">About</a>
</ul>

<div id="page_content">
  <div id="home" class="container">
    <h3>
      Welcome to the home page!
    </h3>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100">
  </div>
  <div id="video" class="container">
    <h3>
      Big Buck Bunny
    </h3>
    <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls></video>
  </div>
  <div id="about" class="container">
    <p>
      This is a very simple single-page javascript application. There are frameworks that do it better, but this one works for now.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```